# How can I write an xpath statement that finds all instances of an attribute where the parent is not shirt element?

Tags: xpath

How can I write an xpath statement that finds all instances of the size attribute where the parent is not a shirt element?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Clothing>
    <Shirts>
        <Shirt size="Large"></Shirt>
        <Shirt size="Medium"></Shirt>
        <Shirt size="Small"></Shirt>
    </Shirts>
    <Pants>
        <Shorts>
            <Khakis>
                <Khaki size="34"></Khaki>
                <Khaki size="32"></Khaki>
            </Khakis>
            <Plaids>
                <Plaid size="big"></Plaid>
                <Plaid size="just right"></Plaid>
            </Plaids>
        </Shorts>
        <Jeans></Jeans>
    </Pants>
    <Shoes>
        <Sandal size="Large"></Sandal>
        <Sandal size="Medium"></Sandal>
        <Sandal size="Small"></Sandal>
    </Shoes>
</Clothing>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `parent::` axis, `Shirt` nodetest, negate the predicate with `not`.

```
//@size[not(parent::Shirt)]
```